# C push & pop test

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Could someone please help me understand what the push_test() and pop_test() methods are attempting to test? These methods are attempting to test something and I can't figure out what that is.

The following code is written in c:

```
int push_test() {
    int ret_val;
    /* movl %esp, %eax    ;; save stack pointer
       pushl %esp         ;; push stack pointer onto stack
       popl %edx          ;; pop the stack into %edx
       subl %edx, %eax    ;; subtract the two values
       movl %eax, ret_val ;; set up the return value
    */
    asm("movl %%esp, %%eax; pushl %%esp; popl %%edx; subl %%edx, %%eax; movl %%eax, %0"
          : "=r" (ret_val)
          : /* no input */
          : "%edx", "%eax");
    return ret_val;
 }

int pop_test() {
  int ret_val = 0xffffffff;  /* -1 in decimal */
  /* pushl ret_val       ;; save ret_val on the stack
     movl %esp, %edx     ;; save the stack pointer
     popl %esp           ;; pop stack into the stack pointer
     movl %esp, ret_val  ;; set the popped value as the return value
     movl %edx, %esp     ;; restore original stack pointer
  */
  asm("pushl %1; movl %%esp, %%edx; popl %%esp; movl %%esp, %0; movl %%edx, %%esp"
      : "=r" (ret_val)
      : "r" (ret_val)
      : "%edx");
  return ret_val;
}

int main() {
  printf("push test: %d\n", push_test()); 
  printf("pop test: %d\n", pop_test()); 
}

/* Output:
  push test: 0
  pop test: -1
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `push_test()` and `pop_test()` is saving the stack state, destroying the stack frame, 
and then doing an operation based on values on the stack.

Let's go through each instruction of `pop_test()` and figure out what it does (`push_test()` is very similar in operation).

`pushl ret_val` pushes -1 onto the stack, incrementing the stack pointer (`%esp`), so right now your stack looks like: `{-1}`.

`movl %esp, %edx` copies your stack pointer into `%edx`, so `%edx` contains the memory address of position 1 on the stack, so right now your stack looks like : `{-1}`, `%esp`: `stack[1]`, `%edx` : `stack[1]`

`popl %esp` pops -1 and stores it into `%esp`, so the stack looks like: `{}`, `%esp`: `-1`, `%edx`:`stack[1]`

`movl %esp, ret_val` takes the value of `%esp`, currently -1, and moves it into `ret_val`, so `ret_val` becomes -1.

finally `movl %edx, %esp` puts the value of `%edx` back in `%esp` and returns -1.

---

This method always returns -1. The idea is to push a value onto the stack, pop it back off, and see if the value stays the same. It also destroys and reforms the stack (by temporarily destroying and then restoring `%esp`). I would guess this is probably some learning assembly kind of deal and not an actual testing method.

Comment: Hans, I understand that, but it's attempting to specifically 'test' something and that's what I don't understand.